# What functions does WordPress use for filtering / sanitizing comments?

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, comment-form, sanitization

We have some custom built comments (ones tied to custom post types, that we can't integrate with WP's comment system). But we want to filter the comments when they are submitted the way WP does and also save them to the DB the way WP does so everything is filtered (not really for spam), basically sanitized for security purposes but also if we get the pretty

tags and emoticons that WP will do. We need this to be safe for front end and backend. As I was able to put in  tags and have tested with SQL injections and also want to make sure that it doesnt get all the wierd \n \r\n garbage.

Comment: Check out the action hooks related to comments [in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions). From there you should be able to find out what functions hook into each of the actions you care about. Most if not all of them will be in [wp-includes/comment.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L0).

Comment: What's stopping you from using WP's comment system and using `wp_new_comment`? (which also sanitizes and validates comments data before inserting it to your database)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wp_filter_kses()` and then `wp_unslash` to filter the content.

Comment: Can you please explain why to do so?

Comment: wordpress comments does not allow <script> tags when anyone posts comments without logging in.
so if anyone is using custom comments then we can use the above functions to filter the content